# Collection of Nuget Packages - Install In A Group

Tags: c#, vb.net, nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way to create a list of nuget packages that you commonly use, in my case Serilog and then the additional extensions for that.

Is there a way to be able to install all the packages in one go instead of having to search for and install each package one by one?

Comment: Search for NuGet 'metapackage'.  (A package with no source/library of its own, but references to other packages.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to create a new project, add dependencies, in this case NuGet packages then under the project menu in Visual Studio select `Export Template`, select `Project template` and follow the prompts.

When naming the project template give the project template a meaningful name.

After completing these steps the template is available under add new projects.

Here is an example of custom templates under VS2019 that are pinned for easy access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this:

1. Create a `.target` file, it is just like a `.csproj` file with `ItemGroup`'s where you can reference your NuGet packages.
2. Reference the `.target` file in another project like this:

```
<Import Project="../targets/MicrosoftExtensions.target" />
```

And the example `.target` file:

```
<Project>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils" Version="1.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="8.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```